# Retrieve data from a specific array from a json

Tags: java, api, android-studio

I have a admin app written with Java to be able to manage my users

I created a custom json

This is what my JSON looks like

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "email": "user1@gmail.com",
    "sponsorship": true,
    "create": 274
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "email": "user2@gmail.com",
    "sponsorship": false,
    "create": 201
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "email": "user3@gmail.com",
    "sponsorship": false,
    "create": 189
  }
]
```

In my List I just display email address

Now my problem, for example if I click on the List which contains the email `user1@gmail.com`, I want to display in a Dialog the data related to this email, i.e. the `userId`, `sponsorship` and `create`

**How ​​can I retrieve the other values ​​using the email?**

I couldn't find anything about it on the internet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When reading your json file, you need to make it understandable.
There is an example of making it understandable in the link below.

**You have to write a condition after these procedures. The condition should be:**

```
for(int i=0; i< employeeList.size;i++){
    if(employeeList[i].email.equals("user3@gmail.com")){
//the person you are looking for
var person = employeeList[i];
}
}
```

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/json-simple-read-write-json-examples/